# XV11 Laser Capabilities

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm really interested on the XV11 laser for an art project using arduino.

Unfortunately I don't have enough money to buy the sensor and experiment with it without knowing a bit more what this sensor is capable of it. My main focus would be to track raindrops. Would it "see" a raindrop falling next to it ? Maybe it's a too small resolution, or to fast to be able to see it?

I don't have a really idea of its capacities.

If someone could answer my question, that would be really appreciate it.

Thank You

Romain

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/118541/xv11--laser-capabilities/) by [Terzai](https://answers.ros.org/users/10906/terzai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I seriously doubt you'd be able to track raindrops with most of the commercially available lidar sensors.

The neato lidar has a maximum range of about 3-4 meters, full 360-degree coverage, an angular resolution of around 1 reading per degree, and an update rate of 5Hz.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0